# How to filter field in loopback from the include model?

Tags: angularjs, loopbackjs

I have this query:

```
UserModel.find({

    filter: {
        include: 
        [
            "communications",
             "roles"
        ],
        where : {
            "object_type" : 1
        }
    } 
}, function(data){
    $rootScope.users = data;
});
```

I want to get all the data from communications model filter by the field "object_type" but it doesn't work as I want.

My Communications model looks like this:

```
...
"properties": {
"object_type": {
  "type": "number"
},
"object_id": {
  "type": "number"
},
"communications_type_code": {
  "type": "number"
},
"address_type": {
  "type": "number"
},
"contact_value": {
  "type": "string"
},
"notes": {
  "type": "string"
},
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To query related models you have to use relation scope. In your case that would be something like this:

```
UserModel.find({
    filter: {
        include: 
        [
            {
              "relation": "communications",
              "scope": { 
                "where": {"object_type": 1}
              }

            },
            "roles"
        ]
    } 
}, function(data){
    $rootScope.users = data;
});
```

Check the docs about ["Querying related models"](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Querying-related-models.html)

Answer (score 0):

Oded, I believe you do not need the `filter` property in the search parameter. It should read like this:

```
UserModel.find({
    include: [ "communications", "roles" ],
    where : { "object_type" : 1 }
}, function(data){
    $rootScope.users = data;
});
```

Also make sure that the other entities that you add to `include` have a relationship to the queried model. Is it really `UserModel` or should it be `CommunicationsModel`?